# Unable to run a jsp page containing jstl tags. says..Unable to read TLD “META-INF/c.tld”

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, maven, jstl

I am working on a maven project in which i want to use jstl. Initially the jsp file was showing exception like classnotfound and unable to find org.apache.taglib.standard.....

then i searched and added c.tld file in web-inf/tags/template folder and also added the path in web.xml i tried keeping it into web-inf/tags also but the same exception occurred
i also added jstl.jar and standard.jar in web-inf/lib folder

I have also added the the dependencies on pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.jpaas.service.securestore</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                com.sap.jpaas.service.securestore.feature
            </artifactId>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>   
          <groupId>taglibs</groupId> 
          <artifactId>standard</artifactId> 
          <version>1.1.2</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>   
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> 
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId> 
          <version>2.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The version of the servlet is 2.5

after all this it doesn't work... :(
gives following errors..

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.NewFile_jsp
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.NewFile_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
```

after refresh it gives the following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /NewFile.jsp (line: 3, column: 65) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/C:/Users/i069130/eclipse/Jpaas-Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/com.sap.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.BUILD-20100618.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:219)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:182)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
```

I am working with maven project, eclipse indigo and sap netweaver neo server which uses derby db

Answer (score 0):

> *then i searched and added c.tld file in web-inf/tags/template folder*

This is not right. Remove it.

> *and also added the path in web.xml*

This is also not right. Remove it.

> *i tried keeping it into web-inf/tags*

This is also not right. Remove it.

Installing JSTL should be a matter of having JSTL API and impl JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Nothing else needs to be done. You need to make sure that your Maven configuration is doing that. So far it looks okay for JSTL 1.1, but your JSP dependency is wrong for Servlet 2.5. The JSP version should be 2.1.

```
<dependency>   
     <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> 
     <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId> 
     <version>2.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to declare the right taglib URI in top of JSP when you want to use JSTL:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.som/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Made the changes but still doesn't work... same prob.. org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /NewFile.jsp (line: 3, column: 65) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/C:/Users/i069130/eclipse/Jpaas-Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/com.sap.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.BUILD-20100618.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV